# popover en div dinamico no se muestra bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo un DIV que genero dinamicamente con una consulta de un form
En el titulo de la pagina la que no es dinamica coloque un popover que funciona perfectamente

este es el codigo

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-md" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" 
title="Descripcion" data-content="<?php echo $palabras['pml']['grafica1_descripcion'];?>"
style='background-color:transparent;'>
<div style='text-align:center;'><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/info--v3.png" 
width="15" height="15"> </div></a>
```

Coloco el mismo codigo en el div que cargo con el contenido de la pagina con la nueva consulta.

y no funciona.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No te funciona porque tienes que volver a inicializarlo. Cuando cargas el documento por primera vez estas inicializando los popovers que aparecen durante la carga inicial, pero si luego agregas nuevos popovers dinámicamente estos no estan inicializados.

Comment: @masterguru como puedo iniciarlos, la verdad el popover que muestro solo copie el codigo y lo pegue no inicia pero dejame sigo investigando gracias por la orientacion

Comment: Teoricamente pasándole un `.popover();` al evento en cuestión.  Ponlo despues de generar el div dinamico. Algo asi como `event.target.popover();`.  Ya me diras si funciona.